# Retrieve value from mysql if it does not exist in other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I try to figure out something but it doesn't really go well.
I have 1 database with two tables.

Table 1: Users
Table 2: Voted

Table 1 has: userid
Table 2 has: votemyid and votevotedid

The second one is the same as userid, how can i make sure that it doesn't select values from users if that value exists as votevotedid in the table voted?

my SQL code till now is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) AS distance count(*) FROM users,voted WHERE voted.votevotedid not in (select users.userid from users) HAVING distance < $distance ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

I can do this, then do a second mysql_query for the voted database, but that get's to much

Comment: you're selecting from two tables without ever specifying a join condition. you'll be getting a cartesian product of the two tables. e.g. 1000 records and 2000 records = 2,000,000 join products.

Comment: You should explain better what you need. Perhaps provide an example.

Comment: Well i have two tables, one with users and one with users that voted on someone else, it only need to select users that the person did not vote on yet: $result = mysql_query("SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) AS distance count(*) FROM users,voted WHERE voted.votevotedid not in (select users.userid from users) HAVING distance < $distance ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"); but if i do this i cannot filter on myid

Answer (score 1):

The method is using the LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT u.userid 
FROM Users AS u
LEFT JOIN Voted AS v ON u.userid = v.votevotedid
WHERE v.votemyid IS NULL
```

What LEFT JOIN does returns all users records and match with voted table and exclude records where voted table return a matching record (by using v.votemyid IS NULL)

I am not sure about your SQL without seeing the exact table structures but it should be something like following with LEFT JOIN.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT u.*, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) AS distance 
FROM users AS u 
LEFT JOIN voted AS v ON users.userid = v.votevotedid
WHERE v.votemyid IS NULL
HAVING u.distance < $distance 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Thanks but for some reason this still gives me a internal server error

Comment: I tried a bit: Unknown column 'users.userid' in 'on clause' when i start deleting things: Unknown column 'u.distance' in 'having clause' and i keep getting errors.

Comment: Use the original Script smozgur posted, but replace users.userid with u.userid

Comment: also remove u before the distance. I didn't see that it was the calculated field in your query.

Comment: Following should be the correct query: I assume lat and lng are in the users table only.

$result = mysql_query("SELECT u.*, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) AS distance 
FROM users AS u 
LEFT JOIN voted AS v ON u.userid = v.votevotedid
WHERE v.votemyid IS NULL
HAVING u.distance < $distance 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1");

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following:

```
WHERE userid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(votevoteid) FROM voted)
AND votevoteid=userid
```

Comment: What is your complete SQL Code now? Also, what type of SQL-Server are you using? Maybe MySQL doesn't support NOT IN, I often use this in MSSQL.

Comment: Sorry i use mysql indeed

Comment: I see, the MySQL is somewhat different. Try "userid <> ANY (" instead of "userid NOT IN (" and please provide the full SQL you are now using

Comment: Try the approach by smozgur, it seems to be the best way. I added a comment on why his code didnt work

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from users where userid not in (select votevotedid from votevotedid )
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) AS distance FROM users AS u LEFT JOIN voted AS v ON u.userid = v.votevotedid WHERE v.votemyid != '1' HAVING distance < $distance ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

When i change the 'votemyid' to number 2 (in other words userid 2 voted on userid 1) it shows up for me (as userid 1)

Nevermind, doesn't work.

If there is nobody in the voted table it also doesn't return anything

When i Add:

```
WHERE v.votemyid IS NULL
```

And there is anyone else in the table, let's say: userid 1 voted on userid1, i (id 1) gets o results back